# hiding and showing radio button and dropdown based on values

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```
<select name="drop1" id='drop1'>
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="data1">Data1</option>
    <option value="data2L">Data2</option>

<select name="drop2" id='drop2'>
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="data3">Data3</option>
    <option value="data4">Data4</option>
```

When I select data1 and data3 from the two drop downs i need to display another dropdown below:

```
<div id="show_drop">
    <select name="drop3" id='drop3'>
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="data5">Data5</option>
</div>
```

else display radio button:

```
<div id="rbutton">
    <input type="radio" name="yes" value="Yes" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="no" value="No" />No
</div>
```

I have tried the following code which works fine if i change only one drop down value. I am not sure of the synatx comparing 2 drop down values and then hiding radio button or the dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#rbutton").hide();
    $("#drop2").change(function() {
        if ($("#drop2").val()  == 'data2') 
            $("rbutton").show("fast");
        else 
            $("#rbutton").hide("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here and see if this is what you had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtJVM/

Answer (score 2):

```
    $("#drop1,#drop2").change(function() {

        if ($("#drop1").val()  == 'data1' && $("#drop2").val()  == 'data2') 
            $("rbutton").show("fast");
        else 
            $("#rbutton").hide("fast");

    });
```

is triggered when either `select` changed, checkes both values

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qEt89/6/
both my jquery functions dont work above..can you please help me out?

Comment: the seconddropdown should show only values depending on the first drop down.
And then depending on those 2 values should show the radio button.

Comment: there's a bug in your jsfiddle. First you're not using jquery, second you didn't close the last `$(document).ready`, third (not really a bug) you can actually let jquery execute your functions **onDomReady** (and drop your `$(document).ready`).

Comment: Also non of the payment plan options have '.data('parent')` so the select becomes completely hidden, and BTW. hiding `option` elements doesn't work cross-browser (search this issue on this site). Just debug your code a little more, and come back with specific questions. (not this doesn't work ... and this doesn't work ... and this doesn't work)